# Can an open-drain pin be used to control an N-channel mosfet?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, open-drain

I'm implementing an on/off pushbutton circuit using the [LTC2950](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/295012fd.pdf) to control 5V and 6V regulators via their enable pins. However, I also want to be able to control the 12V supply since it's used to power an Arduino Nano and another sensor.

My initial thought was to use the circuit below, which I've used to save power on a battery monitoring system in other projects; GPIO is used to control the N-channel mosfet, which in turn operates the P-channel mosfet. However, I wanted to get a second opinion on this idea since the enable pin on the LTC2950 that operates the enable pins is open drain.

[image: transistor control circuit]

I'm thinking I could drop R2 from the design since I'm already using a pullup resistor on the enable pin and I don't want to make a voltage divider. Also, said nable pin is clamped to 5.1V via a Zener diode, since the only available voltage to use for a pull-up is 12V and the enable pin can only handle a maximum of 10V.

Thoughts?

[image: LTC circuit]

Comment: I assume the IRF530 is just from the default selection in the schematic editor and that you're planning on using a logic level part?  Also, is the 2950 going to be upstream or downstream of M2?

Comment: @vir The 2950 is going to be powered all the time. It has to be for it to control M1. And yes, those are just the defaults. I didn't want to commit to a full parts search and then find out this was a bad idea from the outset. I'm also looking into load driver chips as well, which would make it a lot easier.

Comment: That setup should work; I would ditch R2 like you said and you could probably get away with a little higher value for R16.

Comment: @vir what about something like the BD1HC500FVM-CTR? I'm still looking into options, but as an example, it seems like what I'm looking for and in a much more space-friendly package

Comment: Sure, if you want the extra features.  You can probably find something that will roll in the functionality of the LTC2950 as well.  Just depends on how much you want to spend and how much redesign you want to do.

Comment: I'll stick with the LTC for the 5 & 6V regulators. It's already proven to work. This is something to control the source voltage and make it so that the on-off functionality provided by the LTC applies to every device on the board